# Unable to login to developer Spotify, and not getting dashboard on it

Tags: spotify-app

[image: Error]

I have been trying to log in to developer Spotify to create an app using React. But I cannot log in, although I logged in successfully many times it again asks login. And it shows an error pop-up that vanishes in a jiffy. I want to go through the dashboard, but dashboard option is not appearing in menu. So, I tried to log in to the dashboard from Web API option but an error occurred. Kindly, help me.